# How to make colspan with display:column

Tags: java, jsp, el, jsp-tags, displaytag

I want to make a `colspan` in a display:column so I tried to do it as follows:

```
<display:column style="width=50% colspan=2 " title="${textResources['Exam.endDate']}">
```

but it doesn't work it seems that this property is not allowed in a display:column so how to do that?

Comment: Are you using displayTag ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a colspan to the display column you have to create a [Table Decorator](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_decorators.html) extends the TableDecorator class, override the method init, in this method you need to get the header for your cell and add the colspan attribute.

```
package org.hannibal.utils.view.decorators;    
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;

import org.displaytag.decorator.TableDecorator;
import org.displaytag.model.HeaderCell;
import org.displaytag.model.TableModel;
import org.displaytag.util.HtmlAttributeMap;

public class ColspanTableDecorator extends TableDecorator {

    @Override
    public void init(PageContext pageContext, Object decorated,
            TableModel tableModel) {
        super.init(pageContext, decorated, tableModel);
        List headersList = tableModel.getHeaderCellList(); 
        HeaderCell myHeader = (HeaderCell)headersList.get(0);
        HtmlAttributeMap map = myHeader.getHeaderAttributes();
        map.put("colSpan", "2");            
    }   
}
```

And in the jsp I use it so.

```
<display:table name="sessionScope.employees" pagesize="10" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
        decorator="org.hannibal.utils.view.decorators.ColspanTableDecorator">
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: what is myHeader, please give a more detailed answer

Comment: for my case i will add the decorator attribute to the display:column not to the dipslay:table

Comment: No you have to add it to the display table, I'm not sure if there is a ColumnDecorator, I test it using the decorator for the display table

Comment: but i want the colspan behavior to be for a specific column not for all the columns

Comment: Unable to ColspanTableDecorator due to a java.lang.ClassCastException exception

Comment: If you see the code I get only the column 0 "headersList.get(0)" so it apply only to the column 0, so you must get what cells you want to add the colspan, but it apply to the table not to display:column.

Comment: ClassCastException???, you are using the same import packages??, I test it in my project and I don't have that problem.