# How to add colspan to header using displaytag?

Tags: java, html, displaytag

I am using displaytag java library to show  the records from database on JSP page.
I want to show two columns under one header and this will repeat for 4 times. Like

```
 -----------------------------------------
 | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
 -----------------------------------------
 |col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
 -----------------------------------------
```

I used TableDecorator but I couldn't get it work correctly.

Please share any example so that desired output can be drawn.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594555/1662938

Comment: @LeonBorko I tried it but it didn't work.  I mean it works but is not satisfying the need